# Generate SQLite table structure from dataset

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, dataset, migrate

We are using serialized C# dataset as embedded database and we would like to migrate structure and data to SQLite. Is there any convenient way how to create tables and insert data to SQLite from dataset

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Currently I am using .net framework 4

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use this object to build your CREATE TABLE command http://darrylagostinelli.com/2011/06/27/create-a-sql-table-from-a-datatable-in-c-net/.

Then I would use SQL BulkCopy rather than separate INSERT statements.

```
public static void BulkInsertDataTable(string connectionString, string tableName, DataTable table)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                    new SqlBulkCopy
                    (
                    connection,
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction,
                    null
                    );

                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                connection.Open();

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: That link you provided me is not accessible anymore. Do you have another source?

Comment: You can view this article is very useful to you (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14528/Generate-SQL-INSERT-commands-programmatically)